# Excel - How to fill in incrementing numbers in column starting from 1 until the value in another columns stays the same

Tags: excel

I'm having this test case spreadsheet that I need to convert into different format in order to export it to another test management system.

Currently, our spreadsheet looks like this:

```
    A | B | C..
------|---|---
TC-01 |MED|
      |   |
TC-02 |Hi-|
      |   |
      |   |
TC-03 |Low|
      |   |
```

We need to convert it to:

```
    A | B | C
  ----|---|---
TC-01 |MED|-1-
      |   |-2-
TC-02 |Hi-|-1-
      |   |-2-
      |   |-3-
TC-03 |Low|-1-
      |   |-2-
```

...where each TC in column A would start with '1' in column C, and end whenever new TC starts.

New Test management system supports this specific format only, so we have to convert it only this way.
Is there a possibility to automate this? We have tens of sheets with thousands of lines in each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **C1** enter *1*.  In **C2**  enter:

```
=IF(A2<>"",1,C1+1)
```

and copy down